# What should i do if i get Traceback (most recent call last) error?

Tags: silhouette

I have an error while run the code

## 2nd Plot showing the actual clusters formed

```
colors = cm.nipy_spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
**ax2.scatter (X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker=".", s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7, c=colors, edgecolor="k")**
```

the error is
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6112/2610634242.py in 
87     colors = cm.nipy_spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
88     ax2.scatter(
---> 89         X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker=".", s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7, c=colors, edgecolor="k"
90     )
91

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last)" isn't the error message, it's the heading of the following text, which _traces back_ through the functions that were called. The actual error is "TypeError".

Comment: I check the code and there is no TypeError, and i tried to run it few time, and the error still appear. TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key